# Show a field on the SMART CAPTURE form when the previous value is filled

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, form, smart-capture

I am looking for a solution where I want to show a hidden field on the form layout when the previous value is filled in.
For Example : I have previous field Opt_Out_Reason with some values in it and when someone select this this field and input any value after that I want to show the field 'Comments' otherwise it will be hidden field.

How can I achieve this solution?

Please help me with this!

Thanks
Adam